# Access custom event Object using vue directives

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, dom-events

I have a simple vue app with single *leaflet* map component. I'm trying to get `latlng` parameter from Object passed by click event on map, as in the *Leaflet* tutorial.

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    alert("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng);
}

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

I'm able to achieve it using this function placed in mounted() lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
   // (...)
   this.map.on('click', (event) => this.savedEvent = event);
}
```

But what I would like to do is access event returning Object using Vue directive. I tried to do it in this way:

```
methods: {
    // (...)
onMapClick: function(e) {
      this.savedEvent = e;
    },
}
```

With this directive:

```
<div id="mapid" @click="onMapClick($event)">
</div>
```

But it returns MouseEvent, not the Object I want to get.

Comment: could talk more about that object that you want to pass as parameter?

Comment: I'm not trying to pass an object, I'm trying to retrieve Object, which Leaflet map returns on click. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#mouseevent

Comment: did you try to add a second parameter like `@click="onMapClick$event,myobj)"` and return it as `nMapClick: function(e,o) {..`